# object importing in Three.js

Tags: three.js, .obj

http://victorribeiro.com/modelo3D

If you take a look at the example above, you can see a low poly model in .obj format with some texture baked on it. My question is:
Is there a way that I import this same model, apply on material on the body and another material on the eyes? If you look close, you will see it's the same model with 3 elements: 1 body and 2 eyes.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could separate your model into the three elements then you would be able to do what you want. I looked at pig.obj and there is now way to distinguish the different elements. You only have one group in the model file defined. If you could also export material then your elements would be named and in your traverse function you could also check the name of the element.

Comment: I know nothing about this traverse function. Do you have some working example so I can take a look?

Comment: Oh, that's ok. But I just modified this example from three.js r57 examples folder, I'm not very sure what I'm doing, haha. Thanks anyway.