# three.js - Add Material to OBJ Loader (WEBGL)

Tags: three.js, webgl

**Hi, i tried already different sourcecodes for adding material to a geometry but if i add code like this:**

```
var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00, wireframe: true } );
```

**i dont get shading /material to my obj (model) . its like a flat view.
Example: *http://dev.interactive-creation-works.net/Three/viewer.html***

```
// This string has to be the path to your texture file.
loader.load( '0.jpg' );

/*** OBJ Loading ***/
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

// As soon as the OBJ has been loaded this function looks for a mesh
// inside the data and applies the texture to it.
loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
var object = event.content;
object.traverse( function ( child ) {
  if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
    child.material.map = texture;
  }
} );

 // object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, [ new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(), new   THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff4400, wireframe: true, wireframeLinewidth: 2 } ) ] );
object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry);

// My initial model was too small, so I scaled it upwards.
object.scale = new THREE.Vector3( 25, 25, 25 );

// You can change the position of the object, so that it is not
// centered in the view and leaves some space for overlay text.
object.position.y -= 2.5;
scene.add( object );

});

// This string has to be the path to your object file.
loader.load( '0.obj' );

// We set the renderer to the size of the window and
// append a canvas to our HTML page.
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

Anyone can eventually help me out ?

Answer (score 2):

Does your model have UV coords? The code in this question [object importing in Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782701/object-importing-in-three-js) does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Hi gaitat,
Yes it has UV Coords and the texture works. you can see it the Head is red and the Horns are like yellow.

Comment: You dont have a light in the scene. Just an ambient. The directional is commented.

Comment: Thanks , The direct. light makes it a bit better.F5
But still different from Zbrush View:
http://dev.interactive-creation-works.net/Three/character.png

You know eventually a simple code sample of a obj loading and attaching a .mtl or standard mats like phong , basic , lambert ?

And you know how i can vote for your help ?

Comment: The image you are showing I think is post-processed. There is wireframe on top of the model. There are plenty of model loading examples at http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/, at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/examples but I guess everybody would like a sample for the problem they are facing :-) There should be a checkmark under the Answer above. Click it to make it green. Glad I helped.

Answer (score 1):

Use MeshPhongMaterial (or Lambert) without the wireframe attribute to get a material that plays nice with lights (shaded). Eg.

```
var material1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
```

MeshBasicMaterial is always flat.

Also you only replace the texture (map), not material in the load callback / traverse function. You need to assign the material there to the object, if you only replace the map, the material type will be whatever the .obj loader created.